# Replace column values corresponding to keys in a dictionary with dictionary values

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, hash

Example:

```
library(hash)

Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.frame(Name, Age)

dictionary <- hash(c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina"),c("red","green","blue","yellow","gray"))
```

My goal is to replace all the values in the column `Name` with the corresponding values in dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that `hash` is from the package *hash*, then you could do something like

```r
df$Name <- unlist(as.list(dictionary)[df$Name])

df
#>     Name Age
#> 1    red  23
#> 2  green  41
#> 3   blue  32
#> 4 yellow  58
#> 5   gray  26
```

--

**EDIT**

with multiple names separated by commas:

```r
Name <- c("Jon,Bill", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.frame(Name, Age)
dictionary <- hash::hash(c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina"),
                         c("red","green","blue","yellow","gray"))

df$Name <- sapply(strsplit(df$Name, ',\\s?'), function(x) {
  paste(unlist(as.list(dictionary)[x]), collapse = ',')
  })

df
#>        Name Age
#> 1 red,green  23
#> 2     green  41
#> 3      blue  32
#> 4    yellow  58
#> 5      gray  26
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Any idea about the same problem but with two names in the same row separated by a comma? Like: `Name: Jon,Bill` to be transformed into `Name: red,green`

Comment: You mean using the same dictionary? You would need to split at the commas using `strsplit`. This would give you a list, where each list entry is a vector of single names. You would then `sapply` the above method, so something like `sapply(strsplit(df$Name, ',\\w+'), function(x) paste(unlist(as.list(dictionary)[x], collapse = ','))`

Comment: @nabiloeni sorry - I forgot a closing parenthesis after `[x]` I think.

Comment: Try `df$Name <- sapply(strsplit(df$Name, ',\\s?'), function(x) {
  paste(unlist(as.list(dictionary)[x]), collapse = ',')
  })`

Comment: The last one works perfectly, thanks! Can I ask you also why I need `',\\s?'` and not just `','` inside `strsplit()` ?

Comment: @nabiloeni you might not, it's just that often data in the wild has one or more spaces after commas. This covers that possibility. If you are certain there will never be a space after a comma, you don't need it (though it won't do any harm either)